# "No such alert" - error for authentication prompt application in c# selenium chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, basic-authentication

I am getting an error like "No such alert". while trying to switch for Authentication popup. I have added "UnhandledPromptBehavior.Ignore" and given thread wait till prompt load. I don't want to bypass this propmt given details on url. Because, having need like that. Thanks

Note: Prompt loaded on browser, before that code get executing.

```
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

            chromeOptions.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Ignore;

            Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Drivers", chromeOptions);

            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8019/");

            Thread.Sleep(6000);

            IAlert alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();

            alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("123", "12333");
```

[image: Application screen shot with Authentication popup]

Answer (score 1):

That is not an alert from the website , it is a browser prompt. You can use switch to alert only of alerts thrown from websit script using methods like alert()

As it is a browser level window you cannot handle it from selenium. You should use any other tool like silkuli, autoit etc

you can also authenticate directly from url to avoid that pop up as :

if your url was like

https://www.yoururl.com

change it as:

```
url = "https://username:password@yoururl.com"
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: sure. Understood..Let me try that

Answer (score 1):

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        chromeOptions.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Ignore;

        Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Drivers", chromeOptions);

        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://username:password@localhost:8019/");

        Thread.Sleep(6000);
```

Here if your **username** **123** and **password** is **12333**

The url will be

```
       Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://123:12333@localhost:8019/");
```

Comment: Hi @Zakaria, I can do this way. But, As I mentioned in the question, I am having need to handle, so, expecting the way with out bypassing the prompt